# I get this error when I try to install brain.js using npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, brain.js

I always get this error when I try to install brain.js using `npm install brain.js`

Here is the error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! gl@4.4.0 install: `prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the gl@4.4.0 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: What version of node are you using?

Comment: I suggest to try with `npm install brain.js --loglevel verbose` just to see more information in the logs. By any chance do you use any company proxy? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by reinstalling node.js Some packages had issues and when I reinstalled it solved. Thanks for everyone who tried to answer or answered my question :)